# Какую ссылку надо подключить и как это сделать?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

При вводе кода ниже появляется ошибка Infrastrucure.С
Ошибка  CS0234  Тип или имя пространства имен "Infrastructure" не существует в пространстве имен "GameStore.WebUI" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).    Какую ссылку надо подключить? и как в VS2019 это сделать?

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new GameStore.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }
```

Такой класс есть

```
namespace GameStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver: IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetService (Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поменял но ситуация не изменилась

Comment: "Такой класс есть" - где он "есть"?

Comment: в папке проекта под названием Infrastructure

Comment: это все в одном проекте или в разных? Покажите скрин Solution Explorer

Comment: есть у кого нибудь еще какие то предположения? вот ссылка на урок если вдруг https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level2/2_1.php

Comment: какая то фантастика. А в других файлах с кодом в том же проекте можно использовать ваш класс?

Comment: Может, где-то опечатка? Вместо английской буквы закралась русская ('а', 'е' и т. п.)

Comment: @tym32167 не знаю. еще дальше не двинулся. загвоздка в этом появилась , вот и встрял.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да вроде везде английские. язык не менял. пробовал все названия скопировал с оригинала. не помогло. у меня подозрения что не правильно добавил ссылки между проектами. у меня VS2019 а в уроке по моему старая версия использована.